# How does Akka 2.4.x work in A Cluster Application when I loose one of my nodes

Tags: scala, akka, cluster-computing, actor, high-availability

My application has a set of Actors, each one doing some heavy computation, and each one executing a different business logic. At the end each actor sends the result back to the Supervisor that in turn persist the data.

My intention is to have them distribute in 3 nodes to split/balance the workload, as well as make the system high available, by allowing on of the machines "die".

- There is no need to share state among the machines

How does Akka solve for this scenario?

Is it an Akka cluster that I need?

Are there any examples that fall in this domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share state between instance you can use [Sharding](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/cluster-sharding.html) and [PersistentActor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/scala/persistence.html).
You can play [Reactive Missile Defend](https://github.com/otrebski/reactive-missile-defend) project to visualise what happened if node goes down.

There are nice talks on [JDD2015 Sharding with Akka. From theory to production](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2oYytf5Y1rY) and [Scala eXchange - Beat Aliens with Akka Cluster](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/7039-lightning-talks-3) showing how to use distributed Actors (with Cluster and Sharding) and how they behave in situation of turning off one of the nodes.